# Mi ubicación simulada no es detectada por las otras aplicaciones

Tags: android-studio, gps

Estoy creando una app en la cual se detecta que poveedor de ubicación se esta utilizando. Ahora mismo detecta entre GPS (si esta habilitado) y FAKE (si esta desactivado el GPS y está habilitada la ubicación simulada).

El problema es que cuando activo la app en "Seleccionar la app para localización fiticia" no aplica la nueva localización en las otras apps.

Adjunto código:

MainActivity

```
package com.example.a;
import android.Manifest;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Context;
import android.content.pm.PackageManager;
import android.location.Location;
import android.location.LocationListener;
import android.location.LocationManager;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.SystemClock;
import android.support.v4.app.ActivityCompat;
import android.support.v4.content.ContextCompat;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends Activity implements LocationListener
{
    private FakeLocation task = null;
    private TextView latituteField;
    private TextView longitudeField;
    private TextView prov;
    private TextView other;
    private TextView provList;
    private LocationManager locationManager;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
    {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        latituteField =  findViewById(R.id.TextView02);
        longitudeField =  findViewById(R.id.TextView04);
        prov = findViewById(R.id.TextView06);
        other = findViewById(R.id.TextView08);
        provList = findViewById(R.id.TextView10);

        locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);

        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED)
        {
            ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, new String[] { Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION}, 1222);
        }

        int permissionCheck = ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(getApplicationContext(), Manifest.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION);

        if (PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED == permissionCheck)
        {

            if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER))
            {
                locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);
                Location auxLocation = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
                prov.setText("GPS");
                if(auxLocation != null)
                {
                    onLocationChanged(auxLocation);
                }
                else
                {
                    latituteField.setText("null");
                    longitudeField.setText("null");
                }

            }
            else if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(FakeLocation.FAKE_LOCATION))
            {
                // otherwise enable the mock GPS provider
                if(!locationManager.getAllProviders().contains("FakeLocation"))
                {
                    locationManager.addTestProvider(FakeLocation.FAKE_LOCATION, false, false, false, false, true, false, false, 0, 5);
                    locationManager.setTestProviderEnabled(FakeLocation.FAKE_LOCATION, true);
                }

                if(locationManager.isProviderEnabled(FakeLocation.FAKE_LOCATION))
                {
                    prov.setText("FAKE");
                    locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(FakeLocation.FAKE_LOCATION, 0, 0, this);
                    try
                    {
                        other.setText("Inicia task");
                        task = new FakeLocation();
                        task.execute();
                    }
                    catch(Exception e)
                    {
                        other.setText("Excepcion en onCreate");
                    }
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            other.setText("Permisos NOK");
        }
        provList.setText(locationManager.getAllProviders().toString());
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause()
    {
        super.onPause();
        locationManager.removeUpdates(this);
    }

    @Override
    public void onLocationChanged(Location location)
    {
        int lat = (int) (location.getLatitude());
        int lng = (int) (location.getLongitude());
        latituteField.setText(String.valueOf(lat));
        longitudeField.setText(String.valueOf(lng));
    }

    @Override
    public void onStatusChanged(String provider, int status, Bundle extras) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderEnabled(String provider) {}

    @Override
    public void onProviderDisabled(String provider) {}


    private class FakeLocation extends AsyncTask<String, Integer, Void>
    {
        public static final String FAKE_LOCATION = "FakeLocation";

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(String... data)
        {
            double latitude = 40d;
            double longitude = 20d;
            double altitude = 0d;

            Location location = new Location(FAKE_LOCATION);
            location.setLatitude(latitude);
            location.setLongitude(longitude);
            location.setBearing(5);
            location.setSpeed(5);
            location.setAltitude(altitude);
            location.setTime(System.currentTimeMillis());
            location.setElapsedRealtimeNanos(SystemClock.elapsedRealtimeNanos());
            location.setProvider(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
            location.setAccuracy(100);

            LocationManager locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
            locationManager.setTestProviderLocation(FAKE_LOCATION, location);
            onLocationChanged(location);

            try
            {
                Thread.sleep(200);

                if(Thread.currentThread().isInterrupted())
                    throw new InterruptedException("");
            }
            catch (InterruptedException e)
            {
                other.setText("doInBackground");
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onProgressUpdate(Integer... values)
        {
            other.setText("Actualizando...");
        }
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    package="com.example.a">
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_MOCK_LOCATION"
        tools:ignore="MockLocation,ProtectedPermissions" />

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
        tools:ignore="AllowBackup,GoogleAppIndexingWarning">
        <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
    </application>
</manifest>
```

build.gradle (app)

```
apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 28
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.example.a"
        minSdkVersion 27
        targetSdkVersion 28
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        multiDexEnabled true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android-optimize.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies
        {
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-location:16.0.0'
            //noinspection UseOfBundledGooglePlayServices
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services:12.0.1'
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-base:16.1.0'
            implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-places:16.0.0'
            implementation 'com.android.support:multidex:1.0.3'
        }
```

Build.gradle (projecto)

```
buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.3.2'

        // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
        // in the individual module build.gradle files
        subprojects {
            project.configurations.all {
                resolutionStrategy.eachDependency { details ->
                    if (details.requested.group == 'com.google.android.gms'
                            && !details.requested.name.contains('multidex') ) {
                        details.useVersion "12.0.1"
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()

    }
}
```

activity_main.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginTop="40dip"
        android:orientation="horizontal" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:text="Latitude: "
            android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="unknown"
            android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout2"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView03"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:text="Longitute: "
            android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView04"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="unknown"
            android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout3"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView05"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:text="Provider: "
            android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView06"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="unknown"
            android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView07"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:text="Other info: "
            android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView08"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="unknown"
            android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout5"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content" >

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView09"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_marginLeft="10dip"
            android:layout_marginRight="5dip"
            android:text="Provider List: "
            android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/TextView10"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="unknown"
            android:textSize="20dip" >
        </TextView>
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: ¿lograste obtener una solución a este problema?